# Vue.js Axios.post sends variables to php, but I cannot access those variables

Tags: php, html, vuejs2, axios

I'm new to frontend development, and I'm facing a problem that I cannot resolve.

What I am trying to do is open a new popup HTML page with parameters (which I can pass as an array) by calling `axios.post` method from my vue.js file.

I googled possible solutions, but still could not find the source of the problem. Observing Chrome console, I suspect that `axios.post` works fine since it says:

> data: "Array(    [index_id] => 1    [log_id] => 63)…ow.print();    //
>   });", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers:
>   {…}, config: {…}, …}

However, in the popup window, I cannot access the variables, or they are `null`.

The following code is a function in my vue.js:

```
printTransaction: function(index){
    // I have tried this but could not figure out
    // var formData = new FormData();
    // formData.append('index_id', index);
    //
    // axios.post('/popup/popup_output_print.php', {
    //     index_id: index,
    // })
    // .then(function(response){
    //   console.info(response);
    // })
    // .catch(function(error) {
    //   console.error(error);
    // })

    // and this too :(
    const params = {
        index_id: index,
        log_id: logId,
    };

    axios.post('/popup/popup_output_print.php', params, {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.info(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    })

    let newWin = window.open('/popup/popup_output_print.php');
    setTimeout(function() {
        newWin.print();
        //newWin.close();
    }, 2000);
}
```

And this is the very first part of **popup_output_print.php**

```
<?php require("../_/inc/init.php");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
    $index_id = $data['index_id'];
    $log_id = $data['log_id'];

    print_r($data);
?>
...
//Trying to print the value

<?php
    if($index_id == null) {
        echo "index_id is null";
    }
    else {
        echo $index_id;
    }
?>
```

Then the popup window prints `index_id is null`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** following the comment, I just tried `var_dump`, and the variables are all `null`.
:(

Comment: You should do `var_dump` first to ensure the values posted are received correctly.

Comment: @ajreal Thank you for your comment. I just tried with var_dump, it seems they are all null :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is going on is that `axios.post` have totally no effect to [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

```
let newWin = window.open('/popup/popup_output_print.php');
```

this makes a GET request with no params.

From my view, the better approach is to use something like [Vue modal](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html), i.e.:

```
axios(...).then( response => openVueModal(response.data))
```

If you prefer `window.open` option, you can pass variables as a GET params:

```
let newWin = window.open(`/popup/popup_output_print.php?index_id=${index}&log_id=${logId}`);
```

You'll need to change backend then, to read vars from `$_GET`.

Other solution might be to, put `axios.post` into window open template, so it request needed variables after opening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to open a new window. Is there any other way to open a new window with parameters?